# how to export as xaml from 3ds max and maya?

Tags: xaml, 3d, maya

I have maya and 3ds max softwares. Now what I need is to export as xaml from these softwares. Could you please help me with some plugins which can be used?

Comment: There are scripts for 3ds max that export .obj files. Blend for Visual Studio can import those or you can build or search for a .obj to xaml converter.

Comment: Search engines are your friend. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for but for the last 11 years the only way to do this properly and professionally is with our PolyTrans-for-3dsMax and PolyTrans-for-Maya conversion products, directly to 3D XAML:

http://www.okino.com/conv/pt4maya.htm

http://www.okino.com/conv/exp_xaml.htm